# /stats command not working in telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I am writing a bot that will display messages found by keywords in the LAN - this system is fully functional, but I decided to add the /stats command and the bot ignores it!

Even print does not output anything, as if the command does not exist at all

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
import time

# Вставьте здесь токен вашего бота
bot_token = ''

# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

# Словарь для хранения статистики
statistics = {}
total_messages = 0
unique_users = set()

# Обработчик для команды /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я бот, который будет отправлять сообщения из группы, в личную переписку!")

# Обработчик для всех входящих сообщений
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    global total_messages
    
    # Здесь указываем слова и хештеги, по которым будем искать
    keywords = ['сайт']
    
    # Проверяем, содержит ли сообщение указанные слова или хештеги
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.lower() in message.text.lower() or f'#{keyword}' in message.text:
            # Отправляем сообщение в личную переписку
            chat_id = 'CHAT_ID'
            username = message.from_user.username
            text = f"Найдено сообщение с ключевым словом/хештегом '{keyword}':\n\n{message.text}"
            keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Написать заказчику", url=f"https://t.me/{username}")]]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, text, reply_markup=reply_markup)

            # Увеличиваем счетчик статистики для данного ключевого слова
            if keyword in statistics:
                statistics[keyword] += 1
            else:
                statistics[keyword] = 1
            
            # Увеличиваем общий счетчик сообщений
            total_messages += 1
            
            # Добавляем пользователя в список уникальных пользователей
            unique_users.add(message.from_user.id)

            break

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stats'])
def send_stats(message):
    # Генерируем текст статистики
    stats_text = "Статистика по ключевым словам:\n\n"
    for keyword, count in statistics.items():
        stats_text += f"{keyword}: {count}\n"

    # Добавляем информацию о количестве уникальных пользователей
    unique_users_count = len(unique_users)
    stats_text += f"\nКоличество уникальных пользователей: {unique_users_count}"

    # Добавляем информацию о общем количестве сообщений
    stats_text += f"\nОбщее количество сообщений: {total_messages}"

    # Выводим статистику на консоль
    print(stats_text)

    # Отправляем статистику в личную переписку
    chat_id = 'CHAT_ID'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, stats_text)

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling()
```

I tried to change the command, changed the system of counters, added logging via txt and added print for tracking. However, everything is empty: none of these methods helped me track down what the problem is, the bot simply ignores this command, does not read it

Comment: Please read [mre] and try to reduce the code to *only what is necessary to demonstrate the problem directly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use `telebot` but it seems the problem is that you define `echo_all` first, which intercepts **all** updates (`@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)`).

Try putting the definition of `send_stats` before `echo_all`

Comment: did this fix your issue Larry?